# MySQL Client installation error on Ubuntu 20.04 in EC2 instance

Tags: python, pip, mysql-connector

Using cached `mysqlclient-2.0.3.tar.gz (88 kB)`

```sh
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
    command: /home/websiteuser/newenv/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = 
'"'"'/tmp/pip-install-gtzius4s/mysqlclient_581cfbeeeb974b418354ec534fb82b74/setup.py'"'"';
 __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-gtzius4s/mysqlclient_581cfbeeeb974b418354ec534fb82b74/setup.py'"'"'
;f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)
(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-q2ahr_b3
        cwd: /tmp/pip-install-gtzius4s/mysqlclient_581cfbeeeb974b418354ec534fb82b74/
Complete output (15 lines):
/bin/sh: 1: mysql_config: not found
/bin/sh: 1: mariadb_config: not found
/bin/sh: 1: mysql_config: not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/tmp/pip-install-gtzius4s/mysqlclient_581cfbeeeb974b418354ec534fb82b74/setup.py", line 15, in <module>
    metadata, options = get_config()
    File "/tmp/pip-install-gtzius4s/mysqlclient_581cfbeeeb974b418354ec534fb82b74/setup_posix.py", line 70, in get_config
    libs = mysql_config("libs")
    File "/tmp/pip-install-gtzius4s/mysqlclient_581cfbeeeb974b418354ec534fb82b74/setup_posix.py", line 31, in mysql_config
    raise OSError("{} not found".format(_mysql_config_path))
OSError: mysql_config not found
mysql_config --version
mariadb_config --version
mysql_config --libs
```

```
----------------------------------------
```

> WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3c/df/59cd2fa5e48d0804d213bdcb1acb4d08c403b61c7ff7ed4dd4a6a2deb3f7/mysqlclient-2.0.3.tar.gz#sha256=f6ebea7c008f155baeefe16c56cd3ee6239f7a5a9ae42396c2f1860f08a7c432 (from https://pypi.org/simple/mysqlclient/) (requires-python:>=3.5). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mysqlclient==2.0.3
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for mysqlclient==2.0.3

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've fixed it using:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev build-essential
```

then:

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

It was a compilation issue with Ubuntu.

Comment: I had to use python3.9-dev